# implementing login like facebook

Tags: android

I have many activities in my application.
    `First is=Main.java`
    `Second is=App.java`
    `third is =Location.java`

In main.java i have defined that if there is username and sessionid value stored in preferences then directly move to Location activity else show App.java.I have finished main.java in both cases.Main.java is just a splash screen.

I have defined an exit method in main.java that defines:

```
     `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())`
```

If someone logout from application then it comes on App.java.To close application on back button i have called Main.exit() which closes application in correct way.

And on location page i have used

```
`moveTaskToBack(true)`
```

which closes application.

But if i come back directly to Location page after some time my whole application does not work properly its session id expires.

And if i come from App.java page it works well.

I want to create it like facebook if u r logged in and closes the application it starts from second page.and if u logout then shows the login screen.

Please help me to resolve this.

Thanks.

Comment: When do you delete from the preferences?  Using killProcess is bad, IMO, so you may want to rethink how closing will work.

Comment: Hello James I delete from preference at the time of logout that is defined in another activity.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar in my app.  I wanted a way for the user to "sign out" of the application and not just the activity.

So, I did this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
System.exit(0);
```

That code launches the default home screen (exits the app) and then closes all of my activities.  When the application is re-launched, it automatically goes through my MAIN launcher activity (which is login).